# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'selection' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

So I am trying to do a random selection of a list. My code is the following:

```
sequence = [1, 5, 7, 8]

    if counter == 0:

        selection = choice(sequence)


    if selection == 1:
        number1 = pygame.image.load('Number1.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(number1, 540, 50)
        Capture1 = pygame.image.load('Captura1.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(Capture1, 550, 370)
    elif selection == 5:
        number5 = pygame.image.load('Number5.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(number5, 540, 50)
        Capture5 = pygame.image.load('Captura5.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(Capture5, 550, 370)
    elif selection == 7:
        number7 = pygame.image.load('Number7.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(number7, 540, 50)
        Capture7 = pygame.image.load('Captura7.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(Capture7, 550, 370)
    elif selection == 8:
        number8 = pygame.image.load('Number8.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(number8, 540, 50)
        Capture8 = pygame.image.load('Captura8.png')
        pygameWindow.Draw_Image(Capture8, 550, 370)
```

What I am trying to do here is that the program makes a selection whenever the counter is equal to 0, and then it draws that selection until the counter is reseted back to 0, where it makes another random selection and draws it. When I run this code, this error appears, but I do not have any idea on hiw I could fix this and make the code do what I want it to do.

What the variable `counter`does it is the following. It starts at 0, and then it increases its value by 1 until 10, when it resets back to 0. Because of this selection is only defined when `counter` is equal to 0.

Comment: try to think what happens when `counter` is **not** equal to `0`. More specifically, what happens to `selection` in that case...

Comment: Can't tell without having all your code, but you're using a variable that was never defined. Maybe you defined it in an "if" condition that was never met.

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Answer (score 1):

If `counter` is not 0, `selection` will not get assigned, so you shouldn't be testing it.

It sounds like those `if`s should be indented the same as the assignment to `selection`.